# What is the difference between 'let' and 'this' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, closures, function-definition, function-expression

I'm learning JavaScript, coming from Ruby, have done some stuff in C as well.  One example in my reading is:

```
function letCounter() {
  let counter = 0;

  return () => ++counter;
}
```

and is compared to

```
function thisCounter() {
  this._count = 0;
}

thisCounter.prototype.fire = function() {
  this._count ++;
  return this._count;
}
```

In the first example, the count is NOT accessible on an instance of letCounter:

```
let let_counter_ins = letCounter();
let_counter_ins.counter // <- undefined
```

while in the second, count, ~I think~, is an attribute of all instances of the function itself?

```
let this_counter_ins = new thisCounter();
this_counter_ins.count  // <- 0
```

Seems like a function in JavaScript can have 'state' (calls to `console.log(let_counter_ins())` will continuously increment a counter, as opposed to it starting over at 0).  But also this 'state', set with `let` is somehow different than a 'state' set with `this`?  Seems like instances of both `letCounter` and `thisCounter` are keeping track of some counter, but how it is accessible is different?  Trying to understand what the difference is between setting function attributes with `this` vs `let` and why one of them is available externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code, a local variable `counter` is initialized, and the returned function *closes over* the variable (in a "closure"). The value only exists in the local scope of the function - in a Lexical Environment that, once the function finishes, is only referenceable via the `() => ++counter`. There's no way to directly observe the contents of a closure, other than by the methods that the closure may (or may not) have returned or use that deliberately expose its contents.

Every call of `letCounter` will result in a new binding for `counter` being created, a new Lexical Environment for it, and a new closure, so separate calls of `letCounter` will result in separate counts being kept track of.

In the second code, with `this`, `counter` is not a local variable, but a normal property of the instance object. Object properties are completely public (with the exception of the extremely new `#` private member syntax I won't get into), so anything, including `thisCounter.prototype.fire` and external code can access `this.counter` (where `this` references the instance) or `this_counter_ins.count` (where `this_counter_ins` references the instance) and get the current value on the object.

Comment: "Every call of letCounter will result in a new binding for counter being created, a new Lexical Environment for it, and a new closure, so separate calls of letCounter will result in separate counts being kept track of."  How come successive ```console.log(let_counter_ins())``` increment then?

Comment: Because the `let_counter_ins` function closes over the *single* binding of `counter` that was created when `letCounter` was called beforehand. If you called `letCounter` multiple times, you'd have multiple separate bindings for `counter`, one per call.

Comment: ok, so let_counter_ins doesn't actually point to an instance of ```letCounter``` at all, rather, what was ~returned~ (i.e. the function defined with the ```=>```), and that returned function (closure) encapsulates a counter instance?

Answer (score 0):

let is used to declare a variable which is scoped only in its parent bracket. (Not visible outside of brackets)

this is, completely different.
It represents the object owning the actual method.